# Finish level and match player transform with end goal. Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been at this for hours and have yet to come up with a solution. Once the player reaches the end goal I would like the player to match the end position and stop moving. ![alt text][1]

I looked into making the player a child of the end goal, but haven't been able to get anything working.

This is my script.

```
public float speed = 10;
    public float turnSpeed = 10;
    public float maxVelocityChange = 10;
    public float gravity = 10;
    public bool isAlive;
    public Text Score;
    public int CollectibleValue;

    //sounds
    private AudioSource source;
    public AudioClip Spark;



    private bool grounded;
    private Rigidbody _rigidbody;
    private Transform PlayerTransform;



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        StartLevel ();

        CollectibleValue = 0;

    }

    public void StartLevel(){

        PlayerTransform = GetComponent<Transform> ();
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
        _rigidbody.useGravity = false;
        _rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;


        isAlive = true;

        source = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () 
    {

        if (isAlive) {
            PlayerTransform.Rotate (0, (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime), 0);

            Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector3 (0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            targetVelocity = PlayerTransform.TransformDirection (targetVelocity);
            targetVelocity = targetVelocity * speed;

            Vector3 velocity = _rigidbody.velocity;
            Vector3 velocityChange = targetVelocity - velocity;
            velocityChange.x = Mathf.Clamp (velocityChange.x, -maxVelocityChange, maxVelocityChange);
            velocityChange.z = Mathf.Clamp (velocityChange.z, -maxVelocityChange, maxVelocityChange);
            velocityChange.y = 0;
            _rigidbody.AddForce (velocityChange, ForceMode.VelocityChange);


            _rigidbody.AddForce (new Vector3 (0, -gravity * _rigidbody.mass, 0));
        }   

        Score.text = CollectibleValue.ToString ();
    }





    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Triggers) {

        if (Triggers.tag == "Endgoal") {

            isAlive = false;
                    // Here is where the player needs to stop and match the position of the end goal.

        }
```

After searching, I found what I thought to be the answer, I made a public variable for the targets Transform, and used this line of code.

```
  void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Triggers) {

        if (Triggers.tag == "Endgoal") {

            isAlive = false;
            PlayerTransform.transform.Translate (target.transform.position);
```

Problem now is, the player get's moved to a position that's not of the target and the player still moves forward. 
Also if the bool 'isAlive' is false, why is the forward movement still happening?

Answer (score 1):

`Translate` moves the `GameObject` **by** the given vector, not **to** the given vector.  [See the documentation.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html)

You can move a `GameObject` to a given position by setting its `transform.position`.  In your case

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Triggers) 
{
    if (Triggers.tag == "Endgoal") 
    {
        isAlive = false;
        PlayerTransform.transform.position = target.transform.position;
    }
}
```

Regarding the `isAlive` part of your question, you've already added forces/velocity to the object so even if you stop adding forces, it's still moving.  When you want it to stop moving, set its velocity to zero.

```
_rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
_rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
```